# confusing "for loop" in c#, when exit the values get cleared

Tags: c#

I am just new to c#, please help me understanding for loop in c#..

Issue: I am trying to use `j` further into my code but after exit out from for loop , it shows `j` is not exist in the current content.

Is this correct behavior in C# ? how do I get to use `j` outside the loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int j; 
    j = 10;                        
   //print j within the loop, which works fine
 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
}
//print j outside the loop, which throws error
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get better acquainted with variable scopes in C# - there is a lot of documentation around if you google it.

As for your code, if you want to access the variable outside the for loop, you need to declare it outside the for loop, e.g.

```
int j = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     j = 10;                        
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
}
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

In Your code You declare the variable j inside the loop that's why You cannot able to access the variable.

So declare the variable outside the for loop

just like below,

```
 int j=0;   // Declare here

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {

    j = 10;                        
    'print j within the loop, which works fine
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
  }
 'print j outside the loop, which throws error
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks all, sorry to be pest on this but now I am getting  below compile error after declaring j outside the loop at the beginning .. error below       "Use of unassigned local variable 'j'"

Comment: int j;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    
                    j = 10;
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
                   
                }

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());

Comment: For that You assign the Variable with 0 like int j=0;

Comment: thanks, worked for me after assign value (int j = 0) .. as I understood the concept now,  its good with int but  in case of List  should the value to be assigned as well during declaration ? and how to do that ? (ex: List<string> ggstring;

Comment: this is my code, I need to use List ggstring out side of the loop :    List<string> ggstring;
                for (int ggindex = 0; ggindex < 2; ggindex++)
                {
                    gg = cc[ggindex];
                    ggstring = cc[ggindex].Split('~').ToList();

                                       
                     
                };

Comment: List<string> ggstring = new List<string>();

Answer (score 1):

That's not how C# works.

Your variable `j` is defined within the scope of the loop. That means it is not accessible from outside the loop.

See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

If you want to be able to access the variable from outside the loop, you must declare it from outside the loop as well.

```
int j;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    j = 10;
}
```

Comment: Not _"C# works"_ but programming in general. In every programming language you have a concept of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. its out of scope as you've defined it.

Imagine im the for loop, you gave me the job of doing it.. I think J=10 and make note of it a few times.. i then tell you i did the job.

you then try to use a thing I though of ..

You need to adjust the code.

```
        int j=0;
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            j = 10;                        
           'print j within the loop, which works fine
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
```

now j exists, inside the loop because it already is made.. so I come and find a postit called "j" and I can write 10 on it.  You come back after Im done, the postit is still there.